# Dice probability over multiple rows to repeat a specific number

Tags: probability

Suppose I have 1, 10-sided dice. I roll it 10 times.

On the first roll, I get a number A

What's the probability that none of the other 9 rolls will be that number A.

I was writing a short script for work, when I suddenly started thinking about that and I can't seem to solve it a few hours later. All the Google searches led me to results with multiple dices or with some different set of pre-defined rules.

I would appreciate any help, even if it just points me to the solution.

Comment: Hint:  each subsequent toss has an independent probability of being non-$A$ of $\frac 9{10}$, so just multiply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chance that the second die is not $A$ is $\frac{9}{10}$. The probability is the same for the third dice, the fourth dice, and in fact for all the dice.

Since the events are independent, we can use the multiplication rule of probability. Doing this $9$ times gives the answer.

Comment: So (9/10)^9 = 0.387420489 then ? (~38.7%)

Comment: Yes, that's correct.